# Error decrypting my message with Cipher

Tags: java, encryption

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/CodingMain/e6b6a9900371b86f1de435a1de217ea0).

It seems to work when all the code is in one try catch within the main method but not when its separated into another class and decrypt is called through the Security object.

Im guessing a class is not getting initialized properly.

Error:

> ­¬Uˆ±‡Qœò|À'Zâ\\SEPERATION\\ javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:
>   Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
>   at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:934) at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845) at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314) at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165) at
>   Security.decrypt(Security.java:62) at
>   EncryptAndDecrypt.main(EncryptAndDecrypt.java:15) null

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing. Also, don't provide a link to your code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code. Links break all the time and if it does, this question will lose all value.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with the encoding/decoding process. You store DES-encrypted cipher text into `String` objects, rather than first encoding the raw byte output of `cipher.doFinal()` into a robust encoding scheme like Base64 or hexadecimal. DES encryption will result in each byte containing a value ranging between `0x00` and `0xFF` (*0 - 255*), but you then store this output into a `String` (the character encoding actually isn't specified; it's likely `US-ASCII`, `UTF-8`, or similar, but this is platform dependent and can be determined by `Charset.defaultCharset()`). The issue with storing un-encoded bytes into a `String` is that in Unicode, ASCII, etc., not every value from `0x00` - `0xFF` is guaranteed to be a valid character. It could be a control sequence, undefined, etc.

For this reason, first encode the cipher text in hexadecimal or Base64, then store it as a String. When decrypting, reverse the encoding (i.e. *decode* it), then perform the decryption.

Comment: eli5? i dont really understand the encryption scene.

Comment: Data represented in UTF-8, ASCII, etc. is "human readable" -- "Hello world" is really bytes -- `0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f...`. Depending on the "character encoding", the computer knows to represent those bytes as characters you can understand. Each character encoding has a defined list of what value means each character -- in ASCII, `0x65` = `e`. Not every value means something though. ASCII only defines values 0 - 127. But a byte can hold the values 0 - 255, and when you perform encryption, the cipher doesn't care what the purpose of the original data is. So there's a very high probability...

Comment: ... that some of the cipher text bytes will have values that are between 128 - 255. If you try to store these bytes in a `String`, Java does not understand how to interpret them. Even value 127 means `DEL` in ASCII, or "delete". Other "control characters" also exist. So you need to store the cipher text in an encoding that guarantees a recoverable interpretation for every possible value between 0 - 255. Two that do that and are very convenient are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).